# How to set default values of a custom column in Sharepoint for a custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have a list that I am using in SharePoint for a news feed. I have created a custom column called `Page Article`, which is a Hyperlink type that I made required to make an item in the list. I am using a modified list view so that the `Page Article` is showing in the feed so people can click on it and go to the article. The name of the link is also the same name as the title of the object in the list. 
How can I use the title they make for the list object and set that as the default value for the link description?

Comment: is there a reason you can't just start with a link list (one of the standard sharepoint list templates) and then add any extra columns you may need? This way you do not have an extraneous Title column that really serves no purpose

Comment: Well the title column is a default column, so i can't get rid of, and it isn't an issue about adding more columns, it just the ability to set a default value of the page article column with the entered value of the title.